# Is the datastore object in Matlab like a NoSQL database?

Tags: matlab, nosql

I see that you can use `datastore` to hold key value pairs, process data in chunks, and pass it to `mapreduce`. Does this mean that the `datastore` object in Matlab is like a `NoSQL` database? If not, how does it differ?

In case of any ambiguity about what characterises a `NoSQL` database, I am considering as a starting point these  characteristics obtained from dba.stackexchange: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/25/35729

> You'll find that NoSQL database have few common characteristics. They
> can be roughly divided into a few categories:
>
> key/value stores
>
> Bigtable inspired databases (based on the Google Bigtable paper)
>
> Dynamo inspired databases
>
> distributed databases
>
> document databases

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab you can always import java Classes and use any java library, (with the one difference that there is no multithreading). So typically you won’t find many libraries written in matlab that do the same thing as a java library for this reason. In general I would also say it’s harder to write a library in matlab which may be a factor for the lack of libraries as well.
I think your only option is to use a java library, IMHO is a much better choice anyway because java is so much more popular to programmers working with databases, it will always have better libraries which are maintained. The one drawback is that you can’t implement java interfaces in matlab (correct me if I’m wrong). This can become a massive pain.

So not really, here is a Mongo examples on github https://github.com/HanOostdijk/matlab_mongodb